# Inequality of sup and inf of an exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $a<b<c$ and $\alpha,\beta\geq0$, and let $p:[a,c]\to(1,\infty)$ be a function. I came up with the following inequality:
\begin{align*}
(c-a)\inf_{a\leq t\leq c}\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c-a}\right)^{p(t)}\leq(b-a)\sup_{a\leq t\leq b}\left(\frac{\alpha}{b-a}\right)^{p(t)}+(c-b)\sup_{b\leq t\leq c}\left(\frac{\beta}{c-b}\right)^{p(t)}.
\end{align*}
I could neither prove nor disprove it, but I did a couple of numerical tests in mathematica with random numbers, and none of those was a counterexample. So I guess (and hope) that the inequality is true. In order to prove it, I tried the following (supposing that $p$ is sufficiently "nice" to let the integral make sense):
\begin{align*}
(c-a)\inf_{a\leq t\leq c}\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c-a}\right)^{p(t)}&
\leq\int_a^c\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c-a}\right)^{p(t)}dt \\ &=
\int_a^b\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c-a}\right)^{p(t)}dt+\int_b^c\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c-a}\right)^{p(t)}dt \\ &\leq
(b-a)\sup_{a\leq t\leq b}\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c-a}\right)^{p(t)}+(c-b)\sup_{b\leq t\leq c}\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c-a}\right)^{p(t)}...
\end{align*}
But I am afraid that this doesn't help.

Any help for a proof or a (nice) counterexample are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Numerical tests show, that the inequality is not true, especially for discontinuous $p$.